# PushPlugin does not register device and return regid on onNotificationGCM

Tags: cordova, push-notification

[image: Print from console. Execute: ECB and Stopped at registering app]

I have install PushPlugin  with Phonegap 3.4.

The onNotificationGCM case:registered has never execute, I am unable to store the regid in my server database and starts to send notification.

Whenever my app opens, it shows

- deviceready event received
- registering android
- success ok

I have done:

- Changed senderid
- Google Cloud Messaging for Android - ON
- Created server key (But should not be important as I am not at the sending portion)

Do I need:

- to install Google play service api?
- What am i missing ?

I waited for few minutes but there is no registered message like

```
$("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had problem with you. Remove line of codes that contain html thing. If you want to retrieve it, store it into sessionStorage/localStorage, console or alert it.

My html remove version

```
var pushNotification;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// device APIs are available
 //

function onDeviceReady() {
    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
        console.log("registering android");
        window.plugins.pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {
            "senderID": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "ecb": "onNotificationGCM"
        }); // required!
    } else {
        console.log("registering iOS");
        pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {
            "badge": "true",
            "sound": "true",
            "alert": "true",
            "ecb": "onNotificationAPN"
        }); // required!
    }
}

// handle APNS notifications for iOS

function onNotificationAPN(e) {
    if (e.alert) {
        navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
    }
    if (e.sound) {
        var snd = new Media(e.sound);
        snd.play();
    }
    if (e.badge) {
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
    }
}
// handle GCM notifications for Android

function onNotificationGCM(e) {
    navigator.notification.alert(e.event);
    switch (e.event) {
    case 'registered':
        if (e.regid.length > 0) {
            navigator.notification.alert(e.regid);
            // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
            console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
            sessionStorage.setItem("deviceId",e.regid);
        }
        break;
    case 'message':
        // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
        // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
        if (e.foreground) {
            navigator.notification.alert('--INLINE NOTIFICATION--');
            // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
            var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + e.soundname);
            my_media.play();
        } else { // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
            if (e.coldstart) navigator.notification.alert('--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--');
            else navigator.notification.alert('--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--');
        }
        navigator.notification.alert(e.payload.message);
        navigator.notification.alert('MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt);
        break;
    case 'error':
        navigator.notification.alert('ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg);
        break;
    default:
        navigator.notification.alert('EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is');
        break;
    }
}

function tokenHandler(result) {
    navigator.notification.alert(result, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
    sessionStorage.setItem("deviceId", result);
    sessionStorage.setItem("notificationServer", "APNS");
    // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
    // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
}

function successHandler(result) {
    navigator.notification.alert(result, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
    sessionStorage.setItem("deviceId", result);
    sessionStorage.setItem("notificationServer", "GCM");
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert(error, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
}
```

Comment: I have used your code. The onNotificationGCM-registered is never called too.

Comment: make sure you install dialog and console phongap plugin into your project first.

Comment: These are my installed plugin: E:\androidworkspace\pg>phonegap local plugin list 

[phonegap] com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.console
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.device
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.dialogs
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.vibration

Comment: Do i need Google play service api?

Comment: no need. you just grab the project id in google cloud.

Comment: this is getting headache... looks simple but not working ... searching alot for days .. am I right to say the "registered" event will be called everything the app is opened?

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/176 similar issues... could be due to recent updates.... god knows.......

Comment: Hi Mr Dato, are you using phonegap 3.4? just to be sure... Did you change PushPlugin.java loadUrlIntoView

Comment: Do I need this statement in PushNotification.js ? cordova.define("com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin.PushNotification", function(require, exports, module) {var PushNotification = function() {
};

Comment: any kind soul can help ? from the log.. it stops at REGISTERING APP... and no response... I am running from phone with it connected to my PC

Comment: Where can I get PushNotification.js??

Answer (score 0):

Solved. After so many days of searching, nothing wrong with pushplugin or phonegap. This round, it is the phone itself. Many are facing push notification issues on android 4.2.2 especially s4. It also doesn't work on my android 4.2.2 tablet. I not sure how whatsapp and facebook did it, anywhere they are true native app so I believe they have more control for debugging.

How I solved... First i did a factory reset and install the same app.. it works without any code changes! Going forward as i worry that the problem for 4.2.2 would come back, i have upgrade to firmware 4.3 and it is working perfectly now.